# Vector a = b, if we modify a does it affect on b? java

Tags: java, netbeans, vector

we have a following code :

```
Vector a ; // containing some struct info
Vector b;
b = a ;
```

if we modify `b` does it affect on the containing of `a` ?

Comment: Are you actually creating vectors/instances, or are you just declaring them?

Comment: Note that `Vector` is deprecated and has been for a long time. Use a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Justin L. i tried it, but it won"t work i posted a more clear question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731950/keeping-original-vector-intact-when-modifying-its-copy) i hope you can take a look

Comment: @Boris the Spider i already started the program since 2 months and it's so complicated and i already started it with `Vectors` and now am close to finish it i can't get back to use `list` and `ArrayList` besides i don't know how to use them.
if you think you could help me here is a link to the question i tried to make it more clear [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731950/keeping-original-vector-intact-when-modifying-its-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! That's a flat copy. To make a deep copy, use Collections:

<strike>Vector b = new Vector(a.size());
    b.setSize(a.size());
    Collections.copy(b,a);</strike>

Hope that helps.

edit:

hexafraction is right, the better answer is (using the copy constructor):

```
Vector b = new Vector(a);
```

Comment: and that way, if we modify `b` it doesn't affect on `a` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It does not affect it, because it's a new object instance.

Comment: This concept is also known as an alias.  a is an alias of b, and b is an alias of a

Comment: @weiglt i tried it, but it won"t work i posted a more clear question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731950/keeping-original-vector-intact-when-modifying-its-copy) i hope you can take a look

Comment: @androiddev19 i tried it, but it won"t work i posted a more clear question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731950/keeping-original-vector-intact-when-modifying-its-copy) i hope you can take a look

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Both `b` and `a` will refer to the same instance of `Vector` on the heap. This happens with any object, including arrays.

Let's say vector `a` lies at a hypothetical place called 12345 on the heap. `a`'s value(since A is a reference) is 12345. When `b=a` is done, `b` equals 12345 as well. Dereferencing `b` will land you on the same place on the heap hence the same object.

Comment: ok what is the solution so if i want to copy the vector and modify the second one without affecting the first on ???

Comment: @GhassenBellagha This has been asked countless times. Create a new one, use a copy constructor, or find a vector that implements `Cloneable`.

Comment: You need to create a copy of your Vector, preferably by overriding the clone() method.

Comment: @Kon No need, we have [a copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(java.util.Collection)).