# keeping original Vector intact when modifying it's copy

Tags: java, netbeans, data-structures, vector, copy

I want to Copy a `Vector` containing the following struct and the importance for me is to keep the original `Vector` intact when i modify the copied one  :

```
public class objet_poid_n {
   public  int Num;
   public double Poid;
                       }
```

supposing that we have :

```
Vector original = new Vector();
original = filled((Vector) original); // function fills original with many objet_poid_n elements
Vector destination = new Vector();
```

I tried :

```
destination = original ;
```

and

```
destination = original.clone();
```

and

```
destination.setSize(original.size());
Collections.copy(destination,original);
```

and

```
destination.addAll((Vector) original);
```

and

```
destination.copyInto((Vector) original);
```

Unfortunately all of these methods i used gives me always the same problem !! 
Whatever i modify the destination !!! the original one is modified too !!!!!! 
any idea please !! it's driving me crazy ! i don't understand why !! now am stuck since 3 days

```
 Vector copy=new Vector((Vector) allPopulation.get(0));
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
            System.out.println("--------------------iteration num :"+(j+1)+"----------------------");
            System.out.println("sol 1 ------->");
            affiche_resultat((Vector) allPopulation.get(0)); \\ affiche_result to print the containing of the vector just for test



            System.out.println("Copy -------->");
            affiche_resultat(copy);

            Vector muted = new Vector();
            muted = mutation(copy);
            System.out.println("Mutated ----------->");
            affiche_resultat(muted);
            System.out.println();}


    }
```

the mutation function is as follow .. :

```
private Vector mutation(Vector son1){
      Vector topac = new Vector(); // à remplir par les objet qu'on va supprimer
       // dégager les null                 
     Vector son = new Vector(son1);

        son.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
       int j=0,i=0;
      boolean remove = (Math.random() > 0.3) ; // probabilité d'avoir true = 0.7
             for(i=0;i<son.size();i++){
            remove = (Math.random() > 0.3);
                      System.out.println(" remove ="+remove);

            if((remove == true) && (son.get(i) != null)){
            Capaciter_n_objet bin =(Capaciter_n_objet) son.get(i);
            Vector objetlist=bin.n_objet;
            for(j=0;j<objetlist.size();j++)
                     {
                int del =(int) Integer.parseInt(""+objetlist.get(j));
                topac.add(new Integer(del));                    
                        }
           topac.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
            //son.removeElementAt(i);
            son.setElementAt(null, i);
            }
            }                     
        son.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        topac.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        Collection noDup = new LinkedHashSet(topac); //remove duplications
        topac.clear();
        topac.addAll(noDup);  
        correctionmutation(son,topac);
             return son;
 }
```

Comment: 1. Don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). 2. [Don't use `Vector`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) - use something like `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: now am fixing the last points in my project program i started it since a month .. and i started it with Vectors .. no i can't move back and change to deal with ArrayList besides i don't know how to use them ..

Comment: You should post the code that modifies the elements, to demonstrate the actual problem - because it's not clear what you mean with "keeping the original intact" and what "modifications" you're doing on the copy

Comment: You should be using references of type `List` so the implementation is irrelevant to all code except the lines actually instantiating the implementations. That way you can easily swap out implementations seamlessly if necessary (e.g. use a LinkedList instead if appropriate).

Comment: @JohnGaughan i really need a solution for having an editable copy without modifying the original or mess with it's data ..

Comment: If you started the project a mere two months ago why is the code using features that were deprecated in JDK 1.5?! Don't use raw types. Don't user Vectors. And do use enhanced for each loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i ve got the solution from one of my friends, lately, i discovered that if we work with a `Vector` containing some `Data Struct` or a `Class` elements, all the kinds of copy that i mentioned above leads always to a **shallow copy**.
So the solution was to create a copy constructor or function to make a **DEEP Copy**, the proposed function we have got now is :

```
 public Vector copi(Vector copy){
        Vector callp=new Vector();
         for(int i=0;i<copy.size();i++){
                copy.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
                Capaciter_n_objet cno1=null,cno=(Capaciter_n_objet) copy.get(i);
                cno1=new Capaciter_n_objet();
                cno1.capaiter_rest=cno.capaiter_rest;
                cno1.n_objet= (Vector)  cno.n_objet.clone();
                callp.add(cno1);
            }       
 return callp;           
 }
```

And thanx for all your suggestion and ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do deep cloning, A simple way is to serialize the vector and desalinize it again. You will get the expected result. 
Note: Objects in the vector should be serializable

(or)

create a new vector, Then iterate over the existing vector and colne each object in the vector and add to new it to new vector

Comment: You need to reread more closely. Clone each object into the new list assuming it is cloneable. Or use serialization, which is a deep operation. But that relies on the constituent objects being serializable or cloneable.

Comment: `Vector copy=new Vector();
        copy.setSize(((Vector) allPopulation.get(0)).size());
        for(int i=0;i<((Vector) allPopulation.get(0)).size();i++){
          copy.addElement((Capaciter_n_objet) (((Vector) allPopulation.get(0)).get(i)));
        }`
i tried this and it still affect the original vector

Comment: @GhassenBellagha not sure I have ever seen uglier code. In any case you are still not reading the answer, you are just moving references.